# Is it possible to observe the count of an NSDictionary using KVO?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, key-value-observing

I want to be set the badge value of a `UITabItem` based on the count of an NSDictionary. I'd like to do this without too much code. KVO seems the way to go, but I can't seem to find anything on simply observing the count of the dictionary, which makes me suspect this is not possible.

So, my question: is it possible to observe the count of an NSDictionary using KVO?

Comment: My guess is that it isn't, since I imagine that `count` would be defined as a read-only property, rather than a method, if it was observable. Silly question, but have you just tried it?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. I get no calls to my observer method at all for the dictionary. I realize count is a method, but there is some special sauce for collections with KVO.

Comment: Given that in other circumstances (like `NSOperation`) observable properties are explicitly listed, I'd say that you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the dictionary in another object (a proxy) that has a count property that you can observe. You could be all fancy (at the cost of more code) and use invocation forwarding, but you probably only need to wrap the basic -setObject:forKey: and -removeObjectForKey: (and maybe -removeAllObjects) methods, and just set the count property with whatever the dict's count value is.

KVO is overkill for this. From the proxy, dirty the appropriate view/label when inserting or removing an entry in the dict.

Comment: Created a proxy with a count property.