# Observe value changes of NSDictionary inside NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, key-value-observing

here's my `NSArray`

```
carType (
        {
        isSelected = 0;
        kFieldName = "All types";
        kObjectValue = 0;
        kObjectValueText = All;
    },
        {
        isSelected = 0;
        kFieldName = "4 seats";
        kObjectValue = 4;
        kObjectValueText = "4 seats";
    },
        {
        isSelected = 1;
        kFieldName = "7 seats";
        kObjectValue = 7;
        kObjectValueText = "7 seats";
    }
)
```

how can I observe the change of `isSelected` field ?
I used KVO in my code but it doesn't work.

`carType` is a `NSArray` property of `context`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [context addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"carType" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
}


-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"carType"]) {
        NSLog(@"carType changed");
    }
}

//dealloc remove observer
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to observe the count of an NSDictionary using KVO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746269/is-it-possible-to-observe-the-count-of-an-nsdictionary-using-kvo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To observe the change in `isSelected` for every dictionary in the array, you will have to register as an observer *with every dictionary in the array*. As I say in [my book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_key_value_observing):

> You can do that efficiently with NSArray’s instance method `addObserver:toObjectsAtIndexes:forKeyPath:options:context:`, but if the array itself is mutable then you’re also going to have to register for that key with any new dictionaries that are subsequently added to the array (and unregister when a dictionary is removed from the array).

That last part can get really daunting. Under many circumstances, it might be best to give up entirely and just use a custom class that emits a notification when it is mutated (instead of an NSDictionary, and instead of KVO).

Comment: Also, this will only work if the dictionaries are mutable, because if the dictionary itself is removed, the observer will be as well.