# KVO - Observe property of an object contained in a NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

Still not able to digest KVO with NSArray of objects. My requirement is e.g. suppose in a garage there are multiple cars. And I want to observe for change in car tyre properties like is the front tyre upgraded or the back one.

Car.h

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *frontTyre;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *backTyre;
```

Garage.h

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *cars; //Think there are two cars in the garage.
```

In CarOwner.m

```
[Garage addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"cars" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];]


-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"cars"])
    {
       //Here I am able to get the car object which got a type upgrade.
       //But how to know which tyre got upgraded? 
    }
}
```

While upgrading the car tyre I am doing:

```
[self willChange:NSKeyValueChangeSetting valuesAtIndexes:index forKey:@"remoteUsers"];
[car1.frontTyre = @"upgraded"];
[self didChange:NSKeyValueChangeSetting valuesAtIndexes:index forKey:@"remoteUsers"];
```

Should I go [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5692843/2391213) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21821160/2391213) way? Or any other suggestion you may have, please.

Comment: the 2 answers you reference are basically the same, individually observe the items in the collection, not the collection itself

Comment: @Wain Yes you are true, both links are same. However the second one is describing about recursively observing mutable array elements deep down the chain. But the concept is same. Is there any other way to avoid this deep observing

Comment: what are you actually trying to do with the changed information? how is it changed? how much do you use `willChange` and `didChange` explicitly in your code?

Comment: @Wain in my real code, once i receive a change most of the work i do is UI update (user state, map location and couple of custom attributes), storage (NSUserDefaults/File), query remote server

Answer (score 2):

You can use add observer as follow:

```
[Garage.cars addObserver:self toObjectsAtIndexes:[NSMutableIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, Garage.cars.count)] forKeyPath:@"frontTyre" options:0 context:nil];
```

Remember to remove observer when necessary.

Comment: Will this work for a mutable array. For e.g. in my above example, the garage randomly removes and adds new cars. Or should I set observer to the car whenever a new one is added to the garage and remove observer whenever the car gets out of garage. The same is mentioned in my above posted links.

Comment: Perhaps you should re-add observer when array add new object

Comment: Did you mean - 1> add observer on the "cars" array first (as i did already), 2> Whenever receive an insertion notification, add observer on the newly added "car" object (as you said) and 3> When receive a remove notification on "cars" array then remove observer from "car" object. Am I following you? My understanding is that you above code fits only for non-mutable arrays. I have a mutable array whose elements keeps on changing

Comment: This method does not work perfect on mutable array. I think the simplest solution is that you let car tell Garage when it's tyre changed, and let Garage maintain a list who wants to observe the tyre.

Comment: What i did is that Garage observing "cars" array, whenever a new car is added to the array just add observers on the car properties. And whenever a car is removed from the array remove the observers. This is working fine in my case.

Answer (score 0):

After reading more about KVO understood that there is no way that one can observe properties of objects contained in a mutable array. We can observe properties of immutable array of objects through (as @zylenv mentioned)

```
[object addObserver:observer toObjectsAtIndexes:[NSMutableIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, array.count)] forKeyPath:@"property" options:0 context:nil];
```

However to observe mutable array of object's properties here are the steps:

1. Add observer to the array to get notified on object insertion and deletion operation.
2. When received a insertion notification, add an observer to the newly added object's properties that is of interest
3. And when a deletion notification is received simply remove the observer from the object that is added in step#2 (NOTE: the removed object will be in the "old" key of the change dictionary)